# Prometheus tsdb retention time - reduce

Tags: prometheus

Reduction of the retention value from "1y" to "100d".

It made no difference. Should prometheus automatically free up disk space after such a change and clear data older than the specified value?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to verify:

1- Have you configured the retention correctly?

```
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=100d
```

2- Have you waited enough time?

> Expired block cleanup happens in the background. It may take up to two
> hours to remove expired blocks. Blocks must be fully expired before
> they are removed.

Comment: Thank u!. After updating to the latest version and waiting a few hours, everything worked as it should.

Comment: Great, could you then accept the answer?